# Cell array inside cell array order elements Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a cell array containing cells like the following:

```
A=
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
<1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>  <1x4 cell>
```

Each cell contains numerical values like `A{1,1}=[1.6386e+03]    [1589]    [406.9268]    [184.6770]`

Given that `a={'el1','el2','el3','el4'}`, i would like to obtain an output B of the form:

```
B{1}=[a;A{1,1};A{2,1};A{3,1}...]
B{1}=
'el1'   'el2'   'el3'   'el4'
1638.60000000000    1589          406.926813049605                  184.676951989012
1665.10000000000    1614.60000000000    399.333905068047    362.462074500098
1709.60000000000    1657.80000000000    389.181059994089    529.870013181953
...

B{2}=[a;A{1,2};A{2,2};A{3,2}...]
...
```

How can this be performed without writing every cell(i.e. A{1,1};A{1,2}...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use concatenation (`cat`) and indexing to get this result:

```
%Create some inputs
A = arrayfun(@(~)num2cell(randn(1,4)),zeros(10,3), 'uniformoutput',false);
a={'el1','el2','el3','el4'};
```

Then to create your B{1} cell array:

```
%Vertically concatenate the a header with all elements in the first column of A
B{1} = cat(1, a, A{:,1})
```

To create all of B

```
for ixColumn = 1:size(A,2)   %Or, loop backwards for slightly better performance.  IE "ixColumn = (size(A,2):-1:1"
    B{ixColumn } = cat(1, a, A{:,ixColumn });
end
```